# stuck on Matrix Multiplication using pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads

Im currently trying to finish an assignment in which you use pthreads to speed up the matrix multiplication. The  idea is to have the pthreads each work on there chunk of rows

For example: 1000 rows and 4 threads would be thread 0 : rows 0-249, thread 1: 250-499, thread 2: 500-749 and  thread 3: 750-999

```
  blocksOfWork = (BLOCK *) malloc(numberOfThreads*sizeof(BLOCK));

  for(i=0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){
    blocksOfWork[i].threadId = i;
    blocksOfWork[i].start_row = i * rows/numberOfThreads;
    if (i == numberOfThreads -1){
      blocksOfWork[i].end_row = rows - 1;
    }
    else{
      blocksOfWork[i].end_row = (i+1)*rows/numberOfThreads -1;
    }
    blocksOfWork[i].start_col = 0;
    blocksOfWork[i].end_col = columns -1;
  }
```

I'm just having a hard time understanding on how to perform the matrix multiplication iteration, I've put a print statement for debugging purpose but I still can't figure it out, ThreadMMulti Function. Any helpful tips in the right direction would be appreciated. Here is the full code

```
/*Program to generate two square 2D arrays of random doubles and
   time their multiplication.
   Program utlizies pthreads to efficiently perform matrix Multiplication
   Compile by: gcc -o mmult -O3 mmultHW6.c -lpthread
   Run by:  ./mmult 1000 1000 2
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define BOOL int

typedef struct {
  int threadId;
  int start_row;
  int end_row;
  int start_col;
  int end_col;
} BLOCK;


// function prototypes
double ** allocate2DArray(int rows, int columns);
void print2DArray(int rows, int columns, double ** array2D);
void generateRandom2DArray(int rows, int columns,
               double min, double max, double ** random2DArray);
BOOL equal2DArrays(int rows, int columns, double ** array1, double ** array2,
           double tolerance);
void matrixMultiplication(int rows1, int columns1, double ** array1,
              int rows2, int columns2, double ** array2,
              double ** product);
void matrixMultiplicationAlt(int rows1, int columns1, double ** array1,
                 int rows2, int columns2, double ** array2,
                 double ** product);
void * threadMMult(void * rank);

int numberOfThreads;
double ** A;
double ** B;
double ** C;
double ** C_alt;

int rows, columns;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {


  long i, startTime, endTime,seqTime, paralellTime;
  BLOCK * blocksOfWork;
  int errorCode;
  double tolerence;
  pthread_t * threadHandles;
  if (argc !=3) {
    printf("Usage: %s <# of rows><# of columns><# of Threads>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
  } // end if

  sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &rows);
  sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &numberOfThreads);
  columns = rows;


  // seed the random number generator
  srand( time(NULL) );

  A = allocate2DArray(rows, columns);
  B = allocate2DArray(rows, columns);
  C = allocate2DArray(rows, columns);
  C_alt = allocate2DArray(rows, columns);
  generateRandom2DArray(rows, columns, -1.0, +1.0, A);
  generateRandom2DArray(rows, columns, -1.0, +1.0, B);

  printf("after initializing matrices\n");

  time(&startTime);

  matrixMultiplicationAlt(rows, columns, A, rows, columns, B, C_alt);

  time(&endTime);

  seqTime = endTime-startTime;
  printf("Matrix Multiplication Alt. time = %ld\n",seqTime);


  time(&startTime);

  threadHandles = (pthread_t *)
  malloc(numberOfThreads*sizeof(pthread_t));
  blocksOfWork = (BLOCK *) malloc(numberOfThreads*sizeof(BLOCK));

  for(i=0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){
    blocksOfWork[i].threadId = i;
    blocksOfWork[i].start_row = i * rows/numberOfThreads;
    if (i == numberOfThreads -1){
      blocksOfWork[i].end_row = rows - 1;
    }
    else{
      blocksOfWork[i].end_row = (i+1)*rows/numberOfThreads -1;
    }
    blocksOfWork[i].start_col = 0;
    blocksOfWork[i].end_col = columns -1;
  }
  for (i=0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    if (errorCode = pthread_create(&threadHandles[i], NULL, threadMMult,
                   &blocksOfWork[i]) != 0) {
      printf("pthread %d failed to be created with error code %d\n", i, errorCode);
    } // end if
  } // end for

  for (i=0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    if (errorCode = pthread_join(threadHandles[i], (void **) NULL) != 0) {
      printf("pthread %d failed to be joined with error code %d\n", i, errorCode);
    } // end if
  } // end for

  time(&endTime);
  paralellTime = endTime-startTime;
  printf("Parallel Matrix Multiplication time = %ld\n",paralellTime);


  if (equal2DArrays(rows, columns, C, C_alt, 0.000001)) {
    printf("Arrays match with tolerance of %.000001f\n", 0.000001);
  } else {
    printf("Arrays DON'T match with tolerance of %.000001f\n", 0.000001);
  } // end if

  return 0;

} // end main



void * threadMMult(void * arg){
  BLOCK * block = (BLOCK *) arg;
  int threadId = block->threadId;
  int startRow = block->start_row;
  int endRow = block->end_row;
  int startCol = block->start_col;
  int endCol = block->end_col;
  int i, j, k, sum;

  for (int i=startRow; i<=endRow;i++){
    for (int j = startCol; j<=endCol; j++){
      //C[i][j] = 0;
      for(int k=0; k<= columns-1; k++){
      //C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        printf("%lu - C[%d][%d] += A[%d][%d]*B[%d][%d]\n", pthread_self()
        , i,j,i,k,k,j);
      }

    }
  }

}

/*******************************************************************
 * Function matrixMultiplicationAlt passed two matrices and returns
 * their product.
 ********************************************************************/
void matrixMultiplicationAlt(int rows1, int columns1, double ** array1,
                 int rows2, int columns2, double ** array2,
                 double ** product) {
  int i, j, k;
  double ** array2_transpose;

  if (columns1 != rows2) {
    printf("Matrices cannot be multiplied -- incompatible dimensions!\n");
    exit(-1);
  } // end if

  // Transposes array2
  array2_transpose = allocate2DArray(columns2, rows2);
  for (i=0; i < rows2; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < columns2; j++) {
      array2_transpose[j][i] = array2[i][j];
    } /* end for (j */
  } /* end for (i */

  // Matrix Multiplication uses array1 and array2_transpose
  for (i=0; i < rows1; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < columns2; j++) {
      product[i][j] = 0.0;
      for (k=0; k < columns1; k++) {
        product[i][j] += array1[i][k]*array2_transpose[j][k];
      } /* end for (k */
    } /* end for (j */
  } /* end for (i */

} // end matrixMultiplicationAlt



/*******************************************************************
 * Function allocate2DArray dynamically allocates a 2D array of
 * size rows x columns, and returns it.
 ********************************************************************/
double ** allocate2DArray(int rows, int columns) {
  double ** local2DArray;
  int r;

  local2DArray = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double *)*rows);

  for (r=0; r < rows; r++) {
    local2DArray[r] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*columns);
  } // end for

  return local2DArray;
} // end allocate2DArray


/*******************************************************************
 * Function generateRandom2DArray is passed the # rows, the # columns,
 * min. value, max. value, and returns random2DArray containing
 * randomly generated doubles.
 ********************************************************************/
void generateRandom2DArray(int rows, int columns,
               double min, double max, double ** random2DArray) {
  int r, c;
  double range, div;

  for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
      range = max - min;
      div = RAND_MAX / range;
      random2DArray[r][c] = min + (rand() / div);
    } // end for (c...
  } // end for (r...
} // end generateRandom2DArray


/*******************************************************************
 * Function print2DArray is passed the # rows, # columns, and the
 * array2D.  It prints the 2D array to the screen.
 ********************************************************************/
void print2DArray(int rows, int columns, double ** array2D) {
  int r, c;
  for(r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
      printf("%10.5lf", array2D[r][c]);
    } // end for (c...
    printf("\n");
  } // end for(r...

} // end print2DArray



/*******************************************************************
 * Function equal2DArrays is passed the # rows, # columns, two
 * array2Ds, and tolerance.  It returns TRUE if corresponding array
 * elements are equal within the specified tolerance; otherwise it
 * returns FALSE.
 ********************************************************************/
BOOL equal2DArrays(int rows, int columns, double ** array1, double ** array2,
           double tolerance) {

  int r, c;

  for(r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
      if (fabs(array1[r][c] - array2[r][c]) > tolerance) {
        return FALSE;
      } // end if
    } // end for (c...
  } // end for(r...
  return TRUE;

} // end equal2DArray
```

Comment: Why not just use OpenMP to parallelize the multiplication instead of all that mucking around with dividing the work up manually? Examples: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/samples/C/omp_mm.c http://blog.speedgocomputing.com/2010/08/parallelizing-matrix-multiplication.html

Comment: Its apart of the assignment, we are moving on to that at a later time.

Comment: For test development purposes, never use random values, or at least start with exactly the same seed on each pass and print out your matrices as generated so that you can check your results manually.

Comment: `double **` is an array of pointers to double, not a matrix of doubles.